# AngularJS how to correctly inject shared services?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=documentPreviewServiceProvider%20%3C-%20documentPreviewService%20%3C-%20ezursMedicalRecordsService

[image]

The `main module` is importing `commonServices module` and `caseinfo module`, `caseinfo module` is declaring `recordsComponent`.

`commonServices module` is declaring  two services `EzursMedicalRecords`  and `DocumentPreviewService` with `.service`.

`recordsComponent` injecting the `EzursMedicalRecordsService`, `EzursMedicalRecordsService` injecting the `DocumentPreviewService`

I have checked everything:

1. The spelling is correct
2. Each service is declared once with `.service`
3. The child service is declared before the parent service
4. The instance of the service is provided
5. I'm not injecting the `$scope` in the service

This is how items are declared

common-services.module

```
export default angular.module('app.common-services', [
    angularLocalStorageModule, 
    ngSanitizeModule,
    uiSelectModule,
    ngIdleModule,
    angularLoadingBarModule,
    angularValidationMatchDirective,
    uibTypeaheadModule,
    angularRecaptcha,
    signalrModule
    ])
    .service('documentPreviewService ', documentPreviewService )
    .service('windowEventsService', windowEventsService)
    .service('ezursMedicalRecordsService', ezursMedicalRecordsService)
    .service('blobService', BlobService)
```

the caseinfo module

```
export default angular.module('app.caseinfo', [uirouter, uibAccordionModule, uibTabsnModule, "kendo.directives"])
    .controller('RecordsController', RecordsController)
```

the main module

```
import caseInfoModule from './case-info-page';
import commonServicesModule from '../common/services/app.common.services';

angular
    .module('app', [
        caseInfoModule,
        commonServicesModule,
    ])
```

There is component

```
class RecordsController {
    constructor(urls, $http, ezursGridService, blobService, ezursMedicalRecordsService, dialogService) {
        this.urls = urls;
        this.$http = $http;
        this.ezursGridService = ezursGridService;
        this.blobService = blobService;
        this.ezursMedicalRecordsService = ezursMedicalRecordsService;
        this.dialogService = dialogService;
    }

 RecordsController.$inject = ['urls', '$http', 'ezursGridService', 'blobService', 'ezursMedicalRecordsService', 'dialogService'];

 export default {
    bindings: {
        caseDto:"="
    },
    template,
    controller: RecordsController
};
```

ezursMedicalRecordsService

```
class MedicalRecordsService {
    constructor($http, urls, blobService, $window, documentPreviewService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.urls = urls;
        this.blobService = blobService;
        this.$window = $window;
        this.documentPreviewService = documentPreviewService;
    }

MedicalRecordsService.$inject = ['$http', 'urls', 'blobService', '$window', 'documentPreviewService'];

export default MedicalRecordsService;
```

And documentPreviewService

```
class DocumentPreviewService {
    constructor($http, urls) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.urls = urls;
    }
}

DocumentPreviewService.$inject = ['$http', 'urls'];

export default DocumentPreviewService;
```

I really need to inject `documentPreviewService` into `ezursMedicalRecordsService` which used across the application.

I don't why I can' inject the documentPreviewService into the ezursMedicalService. I have the blob.service which is declared in the same way as documentPreviewService, but all is ok with blob.service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the service declaration, there is a white space behind the documentPreviewService:

```
.service('documentPreviewService ', documentPreviewService )
```

I'd assume removing this will solve the issue!